# Value comes in a specific column based on a data from another table in R

Tags: r

I have 2 different tables. In the first table, I have customer details and in the 2nd table, I have their purchase behavior. I want to create a new table in R by joining these 2 tables.
My 1st table is like

[1st Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duduc.png)

and the 2nd table is like as follows

[2nd Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQBik.png)

I am looking for output something like this

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91pcm.png)

I know its very basic but I am very new to R.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

I have tried to use mutate and gather but failed.

Comment: The "join" functions in the dplyr package may be useful for this. E.g. newtable = table1 %>% left_join(table2, by = "Place")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::inner_join` for joining your two tables. Note that I had to add the column `customer_id` to the second table in order to achieve the desired result.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

t1 <- data.frame(
    customer_id = 1:3,
    area = c('A', 'A', 'B'),
    city = c('X', 'Y', 'Z'),
    creation_date = c('12-10-2022', '13-10-2022', '14-10-2022')
)

t2 <- data.frame(
    customer_id = c(1, 1:3),
    area = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
    city = c('X', 'Z', 'Y', 'Z'),
    purchase = c('1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st'),
    days_after_entry = c(17, 45, 32, 10)
)

t <- t1 %>% inner_join(t2, by = c("customer_id")) %>%
    select(customer_id,
           area.x,
           city.x,
           creation_date,
           purchase,
           days_after_entry) %>%
    rename(area = area.x, city = city.x) %>%
    mutate(
        `1st` = case_when(purchase == '1st' ~ format(
            dmy(creation_date) + days(days_after_entry), "%d-%m-%Y"
        ),
        TRUE ~ '0'),
        `2nd` = case_when(purchase == '2nd' ~ format(
            dmy(creation_date) + days(days_after_entry), "%d-%m-%Y"
        ),
        TRUE ~ '0')
    ) %>%
    group_by(customer_id) %>%
    mutate(`1st` = max(`1st`),
           `2nd` = max(`2nd`)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    distinct(customer_id, area, city, creation_date, `1st`, `2nd`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, it's a large dataset with almost 1 million rows of customers and more than 50 purchase columns.
Is there any other way to do this??

Comment: You probably should have those tables in an SQL database and use one of the R packages that can connect.